# CodeIgniter control panel transportation problems

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Provide access to other sites with my admin panel. I sent the admin code:

```
<td> 
<a target="_blank" href="http://<?= $liste['site_url'] ?>/yonet/Yonet?login=
<?=$seesionId?> " target="_blank"><?= $liste['site_url'] ?> </a></br>
</td> 
<?= $liste['site_url'] = I will provide access site.
```

Code to provide access other admin:

```
if (isset($_GET["login"]) && $_GET["login"] != "") {

  $gelenSession = $_GET["login"];

  $sorgu = file_get_contents("http://aaa.net/yonet/Yonet?loginGelen=" . $gelenSession);
  $sorgu = json_decode($sorgu, true);
  if ($sorgu["response"]["durum"] == 1) {
      $q = $this->Kullanici_model->KullaniciOnayla();
            if ($q) {
                $data = array(
                    'kadi' => $this->input->post('kadi'),
                    'giris_yapildi' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('yonet/Kontrolpaneli', 'refresh');
            } else{
                redirect('yonet/Yonet', 'refresh');
            }

        }
    }
```

**Problem**

If I want to reach the control panel I enter the user name and password. I enter the panel but I do not enter the user name and password, do not enter the panel.